# How can i use select to make custom value to compare ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have 2 unique columns. and I want to put another value if I find a duplicate.

can i make it by adding select like this?

```sql
INSERT INTO `invoices` (`id_invoice`, `inv_code`, `inv_date`, `customer_id`, `outlet_id`, `marketing_source_id`, `consultant_id`, `therapist_id`, `staff_id`, `agent_id`, `expired_date`, `total`, `remaining`, `remarks`, `inv_remarks`, `status_inv`, `void_invoice`, `customer_sign`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

 VALUES
(4, 'HD-I-202002-0002', '2020-02-08', 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, '2021-02-08', 440000, 0, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, '2020-02-08 04:54:09', '2020-02-08 04:54:09'),
....
....
....
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(`inv_code`, 12), LPAD(RIGHT(`inv_code`, 4)+1, 4 ,'0')) as inv_codes from invoices where id_invoice = id_invoice;
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  id_invoice=VALUES(id_invoice+1),
  inv_code = VALUES(inv_codes)
;
```

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE. What 2 columns are unique? they are unique individually or in composite index? what another value and into what column must be placed?

Comment: @Akina
the table is already created, the unique columns are the individual unique id_invoice and inv_code.
I want to put the result of the select statement I made above and want to enter it as a value if there are duplicates

Comment: *the table is already created* You see it. We don't. Show it for us. *the unique columns are the individual unique id_invoice and inv_code* - this phrase can have two different meanings.